# How to resend PayPal ipn data?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Because of some reason, I lost a PayPal IPN data log. Does PayPal have an option to resend the ipn data or what can I do? Is it possible at all?

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as long as it's been less than 28 days since the IPN was generated.  Log in to your PayPal account; then, depending on what your account layout is, do one of the following:

- *(Most business accounts in the live environment)* Click on **Profile** >> **Profile and settings** >> **My selling tools**.  Find **Instant payment notifications** and click the **Update** link directly to the right of it.  Then, find the link that says **IPN History page** and click on it.
- *(Older Website Payments Pro accounts)* Click on **Profile**, then click **Instant Payment Notification preferences** (under the **Selling preferences** heading).  Find the link that says **IPN History page** and click on it.
- *(Most business accounts in the sandbox, some business accounts in the live environment)* Go to **History** >> **IPN History**.

This will bring you to a page that will let you search for any IPNs that were generated for your account within the last 28 days.  Once you find the IPN in question, click the checkbox to the left of it, then click "Resend Selected".

A couple of things to note:

- PayPal will only resend the IPNs to the same endpoint they were originally sent to.  If you screwed up the URL, too bad.
- The IPN may not be sent instantly.  The resend request is placed into a queue (like all other IPNs) and processed later.  In most cases, you should see the IPN sent within a few seconds to a few minutes.

Comment: Is there any way i can initiate the resend via code?Are there any API calls?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The only way to do it is through the interface in your PayPal account.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any checkboxes, the status is showing as retrying.

Comment: [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNOperations/#resend-ipn-messages),